# Does dlopen create multiple library instances?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen

I can't seem to find an answer after searching for this out on the net.

When I use dlopen the first time it seems to take longer than any time after that, including if I run it from multiple instances of a program.

Does dlopen load up the so into memory once and have the OS save it so that any following calls even from another instance of the program point to the same spot in memory?

So basically does 3 instances of a program running a library mean 3 instances of the same .so are loaded into memory, or is there only one instance in memory?

Thanks

Comment: It's not called a shared library for nothing.

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was shared, so that other programs could call it. I had a strong but unconfirmed suspicion that the OS was smart enough to only put it into memory once. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: In my opinion this might depend on the OS implementation, but theoretically  the dlopen should mmap the lib and all its dependencies while opening. Then it sounds logically to share the mapped memory between processes for reuse reasons. I guess this kind of a process could somehow explain what you observe. But also keep in mind, your timings might be caused by other reasons like filesystem caching or smth. else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does dlopen load up the so into memory once and have the OS save it so that any following calls even from another instance of the program point to the same spot in memory?

Multiple calls to `dlopen` from within a single process are guaranteed to not load the library more than once. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

```
   If the same shared object is loaded again with dlopen(), the same
   object handle is returned.  The dynamic linker maintains reference
   counts for object handles, so a dynamically loaded shared object is
   not deallocated until dlclose() has been called on it as many times
   as dlopen() has succeeded on it.
```

When the first call to `dlopen` happens, the library is `mmap`ed into the calling process. There are usually at least two separate `mmap` calls: the `.text` and `.rodata` sections (which usually reside in a single RO segment) are mapped read-only, the `.data` and `.bss` sections are mapped read-write.

A subsequent `dlopen` from another process performs the same `mmap`s. However the OS does not have to load any of the read-only data from disk -- it merely increments reference counts on the pages already loaded for the first `dlopen` call. That is the sharing in "shared library".

> So basically does 3 instances of a program running a library mean 3 instances of the same .so are loaded into memory, or is there only one instance in memory?

Depends on what you call an "instance".

Each process will have its own set of (dynamically allocated) runtime loader structures describing this library, and each set will contain an "instance" of the shared library (which can be loaded at different address in different process). Each process will also have its own instance of writable data (which uses copy-on-write semantics). But the read-only mappings will all occupy the same physical memory (though they can appear at different addresses in each of the processes).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.